# Determining what port is associated with a network interface

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, port

I have a computer with 4 ethernet ports in the back. How can I tell what network interface (eth0, eth1, ...) is associated with each port?

Comment: I would start by making a map of physical port locations (top port, port 2, or whatever) to MAC addresses. You can easily go from MAC address to network interface name.

Comment: Is the MAC address written anywhere on the actual ethernet card?

Answer (score 1):

You are maybe looking for ethtool -p . For example :

```
ethtool -p eth0
```

will cause mentioned eth0 LED to blink, so that you can identify it on the box.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all interfaces are up, connect working network cable and check `dmesg|tail`. Should say something like 
`eth<N>: link becomes ready`

If interfaces are down, bring them up with `ifconfig eth<N> up`